# Merge object in array with javascript

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I have three objects (productData, stockData, locationData). productData have two data productId, and productName. stockData have productId, locationId and stock. I wanna to merge it all to a new array. For example, I have three object like snippet code bellow then merge it:

```
const productData = [
  {productId: 1000,productName: 'Product 1000'},
  {productId: 1001,productName: 'Product 1001'}
];
const stockData = [
  {productId: 1000,locationId: 1,stock: 21},
  {productId: 1000,locationId: 2,stock: 8},
  {productId: 1001,locationId: 1,stock: 4},
  {productId: 1001,locationId: 2,stock: 10}
];
const locationData = [
  {locationId: 1,locationName: 'Location 1'},
  {locationId: 2,locationName: 'Location 2'}
];
```

I wanna to merge that object tobe a new array with result like:

```
const result = [
  {
    productName: 'Product 1000',
    stock: {
      total: 29,
      detail: [
        {
          locationName: 'Location 1',
          stock: 21
        },
        {
          locationName: 'Location 2',
          stock: 8
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    productName: 'Product 1001',
    stock: {
      total: 14,
      detail: [
        {
          locationName: 'Location 1',
          stock: 4
        },
        {
          locationName: 'Location 2',
          stock: 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

i have no idea, so far i do like this:

```
function mergeArrayObjects(arr1,arr2,arr3){

  let mulai = 0;
  let stok = 0;
  let stok2 = 0;
  let mulaiStok = 0;
  let detail = [];
  let merge = [];

  while(mulai < arr1.length){
        while(mulaiStok < arr2.length){
            if(arr1[0].productId === arr2[mulaiStok].productId){
                stok = stok + arr2[mulaiStok].stock
            }
            if(arr1[1].productId === arr2[mulaiStok].productId){
                stok2 = stok2 + arr2[mulaiStok].stock
            }
            mulaiStok++
        }

        merge.push({
          productName: arr1[mulai].productName,
          stock: {
            total:stok2,
            detail:detail}
        })
        mulai++
  }
  return merge;
}
console.log(mergeArrayObjects(productData, stockData, locationData))
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: "I want to do X" is not a question.  What have you tried?  How has it failed?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by iterating the productData list and creating an empty product object for each one of them such as:

```
       let product = {
            productName: pd.productName,
            stock: {
                total: 0,
                detail: []
            }
        };
```

Then I would iterate the product list and search for their stock to add to the stock list details while increasing the total stock.

You can also start by iterating on the stockData list if you prefer.

This should do the job:

```js
const productData = [
  {productId: 1000,productName: 'Product 1000'},
  {productId: 1001,productName: 'Product 1001'}
];
const stockData = [
  {productId: 1000,locationId: 1,stock: 21},
  {productId: 1000,locationId: 2,stock: 8},
  {productId: 1001,locationId: 1,stock: 4},
  {productId: 1001,locationId: 2,stock: 10}
];
const locationData = [
  {locationId: 1,locationName: 'Location 1'},
  {locationId: 2,locationName: 'Location 2'}
];



function mergeObj(productDataList, stockDataList, locationDataList) {
    let result = [];
    productDataList.forEach(pd => {
        let product = {
            productName: pd.productName,
            stock: {
                total: 0,
                detail: []
            }
        };
        let stockList = stockDataList.filter(sd => sd.productId === pd.productId);
        if (stockList.length > 0) {
            stockList.forEach(sl => {
                let location = locationDataList.find(ld => ld.locationId === sl.locationId);
                if (location) {
                    let detail = {
                        locationName: location.locationName,
                        stock: sl.stock
                    }
                    product.stock.total += sl.stock;
                    product.stock.detail.push(detail);
                } else {
                    console.error('Location not found for stock data');
                }

            })
        }

        result.push(product);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log('Object merged: ', mergeObj(productData, stockData, locationData));
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

You can group `stock` and `location` data then map through `product` data as following

```js
const productData = [
  { productId: 1000, productName: 'Product 1000' },
  { productId: 1001, productName: 'Product 1001' }
];
const stockData = [
  { productId: 1000, locationId: 1, stock: 21 },
  { productId: 1000, locationId: 2, stock: 8 },
  { productId: 1001, locationId: 1, stock: 4 },
  { productId: 1001, locationId: 2, stock: 10 }
];
const locationData = [
  { locationId: 1, locationName: 'Location 1' },
  { locationId: 2, locationName: 'Location 2' }
];

function group(arr, by) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let key = curr[by];
    delete curr[by];
    acc.set(key, [...acc.get(key) || [], curr]);
    return acc;
  }, new Map())
}

let groupedstockData = group(stockData, 'productId');
let groupedLocationData = group(locationData, 'locationId');

let out = productData.map(({ productName, productId }) => {
  let stockdata = groupedstockData.get(productId);
  let sum = 0;
  return {
    productName, stock: {
      detail: stockdata.map(({ locationId, stock }) => {
        let [{ locationName }] = groupedLocationData.get(locationId);
        sum += stock;
        return { locationName, stock }
      }), total: sum
    }
  }
});
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the advantage of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and collect in the first step some related data with a key. Later take this values for a faster access without iterating the arrays again.

You need maps for `locations`, `products` and `details` of product and location which is empty at start.

From the `products` map get the values as result set.

Finally iterate `stockData` once and get the product and detail and `detail` does not exists for the given product and location create a new object and insert this into the details map and push it to the product's `detail's property.

At last update `stock` of `detail` and `total` of `product`.

```js
const
    // main data
    productData = [{ productId: 1000, productName: 'Product 1000' }, { productId: 1001, productName: 'Product 1001' }],
    stockData = [{ productId: 1000, locationId: 1, stock: 21 }, { productId: 1000, locationId: 2, stock: 8 }, { productId: 1001, locationId: 1, stock: 4 }, { productId: 1001, locationId: 2, stock: 10 }],
    locationData = [{ locationId: 1, locationName: 'Location 1' }, { locationId: 2, locationName: 'Location 2' }],

    // maps as helpers
    locations = new Map(locationData.map(({ locationId, locationName }) => [locationId, locationName])),
    products = new Map(productData.map(({ productId, productName }) => [productId, { productName, stock: { total: 0, detail: [] } }])),
    details = new Map,

    // literally the result
    result = Array.from(products.values());

stockData.forEach(({ productId, locationId, stock }) => {
    var product = products.get(productId),
        detailKey = `${productId}|${locationId}`,
        detail = details.get(detailKey);

    if (!detail) {
        detail = { locationName: locations.get(locationId), stock: 0 };
        details.set(detailKey, detail);
        product.stock.detail.push(detail);
    }

    detail.stock += stock;
    product.stock.total += stock;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another technique, which started as a Ramda pipeline, pieces of which I replaced one by one until there were no Ramda functions left:

```js
const combineStock = (productData, stockData, locationData) => {
  const products = productData .reduce ((a, {productId, productName}) => ({...a, [productId]: productName}), {})
  const locations = locationData .reduce ((a, {locationId, locationName}) => ({...a, [locationId]: locationName}), {})

  const collectStock = (stockLocations) => stockLocations .reduce ( 
    ({total, details}, {locationId, stock}) => ({
      total: total + stock,
      details: [... details, {locationName: locations [locationId], stock}]
    }),
    {total: 0, details: []}
  )
  
  return  Object.entries (
    Object .entries (
      stockData .reduce ((a, {productId, ... rest}) => ({... a, [productId]: [... (a [productId] || []), rest]}), {})
    ) 
    .reduce ((a, [k, v]) => ({... a, [k]: collectStock (v)}), {})
  )
  .map (([productId, stock]) => ({
    productName: products [productId],
    stock
  })) 
}

const productData = [{productId: 1000, productName: 'Product 1000'}, {productId: 1001, productName: 'Product 1001'}]
const stockData = [{productId: 1000, locationId: 1, stock: 21}, {productId: 1000, locationId: 2, stock: 8}, {productId: 1001, locationId: 1, stock: 4}, {productId: 1001, locationId: 2, stock: 10}]
const locationData = [{locationId: 1, locationName: 'Location 1'}, {locationId: 2, locationName: 'Location 2'}]

console .log (combineStock (productData, stockData, locationData))
```

This proceeds in several steps.

The first line turns `productData` into something like this:

```js
{1000:"Product 1000", 1001: "Product 1001"}
```

and the next one does something similar for `locationData`.  These just make it easier to look up their names given the ids.

We define the `collectStock` helper, which will transform an array like this:

```js
[{locationId: 1, stock: 21}, {locationId: 2, stock: 8}]
```

into this:

```js
{
  total: 29,
  details: [{locationName: "Location 1", stock: 21}, {locationName: "Location 2", stock: 8}]
}
```

using the `locations` lookup.

The remainder is the main function.  The `stockData .reduce (...)` line creates a structure like this:

```js
{
  "1000": [{"locationId": 1, "stock": 21}, {"locationId": 2, "stock": 8}], 
  "1001": [{"locationId": 1, "stock": 4}, {"locationId": 2, "stock": 10}]
}
```

After wrapping that up with `Object.entries` and calling the `reduce` on it with the call to `collectStock`, we get something like this:

```js
{
  1000: {
    total: 29,
    details: [{locationName: "Location 1", stock: 21}, {locationName: "Location 2", stock: 8}]
  }, 
  1001: {
    total: 14,
    details: [{locationName: "Location 1", stock: 4}, {locationName: "Location 2", stock: 10}] 
  }
}
```

We then call `Object.entries` on that result and `map` the resulting pairs into our final format, using the `products` lookup.

Comment: do you have an idea, if an object is faster than a map and depending on creating, if for objects your method or s/t like `(o[k], o)` faster and with map to take a mapped full array (as i do) or a reduce with `map.add(k, o)`? and ... what is best paractice?

Comment: @NinaScholz: I don't know which technique would be faster to create.  We could of course write a quick performance test for that.  But for access, I would bet that `obj[key]` is faster than `map.get(key)`; there's been years more to optimize that and it doesn't involve a function call.  However, unless the expected data is fairly large, the best performance might quite possibly be in not creating any separate data structure and only doing a `find` on the original array.  I simply don't like the uglier code that would entail.

Comment: that sounds comprehensible.